# How to remux 3D MKV (MVC) to AVCHD 3D?

Tags: matroska, 3d, mts, avchd, mvc

3D MKV MVC is nice but not widely supported.  AVCHD 3D is supported on latest line of TV/BD player.  Is there a way to remux H264 MVC in MKV to AVCHD 3D MTS?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb outfile.mts
```

If you want to try `.mp4` with AAC audio, one of these might work

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -c:v copy outfile.mp4
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -c:v copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb outfile.mp4
```

Comment: I cannot confirm if this works or not.  I ran it and it did generate a .mts file but my TV which claims it supports AVCHD 3D cannot play the file.

Comment: would MVC stream in .mp4 work?  I haven't tried

Comment: I'm not sure if .mp4 will work with DTS audio